# php money_format change location of negative sign

Tags: php, currency, money-format

I am looking to localize money values on my website, and I have run into an issue with negative numbers using PHP's `money_format()`

When I have the locale set to `fr_CA` (Canadian French), the negative sign for negative values is appearing after the string, but it should appear before the string.

For example, the following will output `4 946 261 $-` when it should be `-4 946 261 $`

```
$number = -4946261;
echo money_format('%.0n', $number);
```

Comment: echo money_format('%+n', -123.45); // -$123.45

Comment: @bxN5 that isn't using locale fr_CA

Comment: I am having the exact same issue.